# On Duplicate Key only update Null or empty values

Tags: mysql, merge, duplicates

I've a mysql query to merge two tables on primary key IMO. The query works fine however the issue I have is that on Duplicate key update, I only want to update wp_second table's those fields that have no values.

So in short words, On duplicate key .. wp_second values should be only updated if null or empty.

here is query I've so far

```
INSERT INTO wp_second (imo, GEARTYPE, vname, flag) SELECT imo_number, vessel_type, vessel_name, flag FROM wp_first
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
wp_second.GEARTYPE=wp_first.vessel_type,
wp_second.flag=wp_first.flag,
wp_second.vname=wp_first.vessel_name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with coalesce

```
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   wp_second.GEARTYPE= COALESCE(wp_first.vessel_type, wp_second.GEARTYPE),
   wp_second.flag= COALESCE(wp_first.flag, wp_second.flag),
   wp_second.vname= COALESCE(wp_first.vessel_name, wp_second.vname)
```

? is the value you want to be if null

Comment: if null i want to update the field with wp_first value .. if not Null or empty then ignore.. can you help?

Comment: yes COALESCE() returns first non null value from its arguments.

Comment: By the way my final query looks like this

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wp_second.GEARTYPE=
IFNULL(NULLIF( wp_first.vessel_type,''),wp_second.GEARTYPE)